# Convert IDA imagebase to detours

Tags: ida, disassembly

I have succefully hooked a game with imagebase 400000 (Ex:

```
//  LRESULT __stdcall sub_6D5040(int a1, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, int a4)

Game.SecondaryFunctHookAddress = "0x2D5040"
```

and the game work.

Now I have another game with imagebase: 140000000

```
// __int64 __fastcall sub_1405B4B60(__int64 *a1)
```

I have tried:

```
Game.SecondaryFunctHookAddress = "0x0005B4B60"
```

but not work becouse detour don't attach the address.

until now I have converted the address with this function:

```
    DWORD GetGameFunctionAddress(std::string GameFileExe, std::string Address)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// Get integer value address of the original function hook  //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
        return (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA(GameFileExe.c_str()) + std::strtoul(Address.c_str(), NULL, 16);
}
```

and always work, but now there is a imagebase of 140000000 and seem more complicated.

Can you please tell me what is the right address for sub_1405B4B60 converted to string ?

Best Regards

Comment: Most modern programs don't use a static base address, instead because of ASLR the base address is different on every start. So the common way to calculate the address of a function is: 1. Use the address shown in IDA and substract the IDA base address from it. 2. At run-time get the current base address of the executable (or the library) and add the result of 1. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066847/why-does-getting-the-base-address-using-getmodulehandle-work) `GetModuleHandleA` does not work to get the base address if the process is 64bit.

Comment: Thank you I have do some progress: the address variable was "DWORD" now I have replaced to "__int64" and now the game start. But after 15 second crash and I get a message from game "Signature Verification of executible failed". If I remove the line: "DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookSoundFunction, HookMainFunction);" the game work fine. Any Ideas ?